setting rpath for executable on macOS with CMAKE
I am trying to build an executable that uses several dylibs in the execution path. This works for some, but for one it doesn't and I do not understand why.
otool -L shows the following:
@rpath/libtuio.dylib (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
@rpath/liburg_library.dylib (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
/libIrrlicht.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)

The library it does not work for is libIrrlicht, which, I think, should also have @rpath/ in front of it, but I do not know how to make CMake do that.
Linker command generated by CMake:
/usr/bin/clang++ -g -arch arm64 
[...]
-Wl,-rpath,@loader_path/
[...]
bin/libtuio.dylib 
bin/liburg_library.dylib
[...]
external/lib_mac_arm/libIrrlicht.dylib

The obvious difference is that libtuio and liburg_library are compiled in the process, while libIrrlicht is precompiled and supplied - but copied to the executable folder post-build.
The relevant section in the CMakeLists.txt is:
target_link_libraries(myBinary [...] ${TUIO_LIB_TARGET} ${URG_LIB_TARGET} ${OSC_LIB_TARGET}) 

if (MACOSX)
    target_link_libraries(myBinary [...] ${IRR_LIB_DIR}/libIrrlicht.dylib opencv_core opencv_video ${OPENSSL_CRYPTO_LIBRARIES} ${SDL2_LIBRARIES})
    set_target_properties(myBinary PROPERTIES BUILD_WITH_INSTALL_RPATH TRUE)
    set_property(
        TARGET myBinary
        PROPERTY INSTALL_RPATH
        "@loader_path/"
    )


Looks like the library libIrrlicht.dylib has install name /libIrrlicht.dylib. Exactly this name is embedded into the executable which it links with the library. You need to either rebuild the library with proper install name, or use install_name_tool to fix that.

thank you, your comment helped. I was able to fix it with install_name_tool -change /libIrrlicht.dylib @loader_path/libIrrlicht.dylib myBinary after compiling. Not the ideal solution, but it works.
